# Laravel query builder with joins

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am blocked in the conversion of my raw sql query to laravel query builder. Can someone give me a hand on the issue?

```
select p.name, p.`type`, p.`status`, p.state, ps1.* from pos_session ps1 right join pos p on ps1.pos_id = p.id where ps1.id = (select max(ps0.id) from pos_session ps0 where ps0.pos_id = ps1.pos_id) or p.site_id = '2' order by ps1.pos_id;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I see your ps0 and ps1 both be `pos_session`? so what does this mean: `ps0.pos_id = ps1.pos_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
 DB::table('pos_session AS ps1')
        ->select('p.name','p.type','p.status','p.state','ps1.*')
        ->rightJoin('pos AS p','ps1.pos_id','=','p.id')
        ->where('ps1.id','=',function($query){
            $query->select(DB::raw('MAX(ps0.id)'))
                ->from('pos_session AS ps0')
                ->where('ps0.pos_id','=','ps1.pos_id');
        })
        ->orWhere('p.site_id','=',2)
        ->orderBy('ps1.pos_id')
        ->get();
```

you can achieve the results through join as well:

```
DB::table('pos_session AS ps1')
            ->select('p.name','p.type','p.status','p.state','ps1.*')
            ->rightJoin('pos AS p','ps1.pos_id','=','p.id')
            ->join('pos_session AS ps0', 'ps0.pos_id', '=', 'ps1.pos_id')
            ->where('ps1.id','=',DB::raw('MAX(ps0.id)'))
            ->orWhere('p.site_id','=',2)
            ->orderBy('ps1.pos_id')
            ->get();
```

Hope it helped :)